# How I end a loop for not sum first and last number as a pair?

Tags: python, loops, sum, max, neighbours

I've got everything working correctly except this one problem - with the third output it says the max pair sum is 13 due to taking sum of the first and last number. It should be 11 (as 9+2 or 4+7). I can't figure it out how I fix this problem - ending the loop with the first and last position.

Thank you for all advice.

```
def _sum(num_list): 
    maxSum = -9999999
    for i in range(len(num_list)): 
        for j in range(i-1, i+1):
            if not num_list[i] == num_list[j]:
                maxSum = max(maxSum, num_list[i] + num_list[j])
    return maxSum        

print(_sum([1, 8, 7, 3, 5, 2])) 
# correct answer: 15
print(_sum([1, 2, 45, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2]))
# correct answer: 49
print(_sum([9, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
# correct answer: 11
```

I have tried write some if conditions into for j loop but it ended up with many errors. I'm truly out of ideas and I can't even imagine how it could be right.

Comment: So why are `9` and `4` not a pair of numbers from `num_list`?

Comment: The task says that the correct asnwer should be 11, so I've deduced that the 9 and 4 are not neighbours and both have only one, not two like the rest of the numbers. And I can't figure out how to write this condition to this code.

Answer (score 0):

in your solution, for first element value of j is [-1, 0] beacuse of this it is taking 4 and adding with 0th index element and making their sum as max value. you need to fix it by starting from index 1. A simple way to do that is below

```
def _sum(num_list): 
    maxSum = -9999999
    for i in range(1, len(num_list)): 
        for j in range(i-1, i+1):
            if not num_list[i] == num_list[j]:
                maxSum = max(maxSum, num_list[i] + num_list[j])
    return maxSum
```

Comment: Oh gosh thank you so much, that was really easy :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.pairwise` for this.

Your code considers *every* possible pairing of elements from the given array. `pairwise` only considers consecutive pairs:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

def _sum(num_list):
    return sum(max(pairwise(num_list), key=lambda item: item[0]+item[1]))
```

Output as requested